# MySQL group by/merge data

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to find a way to merge data via a SELECT query. The table is like the following:

```
sku     condition   make      model       derivative    height    length     depth
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     new         ford      test        212           1.28      9.0       
234     new         ford      test        212
345     new         ford      test        212                                4.9
456     new         bmw       awesome                   3.33      3.33
789     new         bmw       cool        123           2.23                 9.89
987     new         bmw       cool        123                     1.99
...            ...              ...           ...           ...         ...         ...
```

What I need to do somehow is group by the "best available" data. I have tried to group by each column but unexpected results happen.

This is what I am hoping to return:

```
sku     condition   make      model       derivative    height    length     depth
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123     new         ford      test        212           1.28      9.0        4.9
234     new         ford      test        212           1.28      9.0        4.9
345     new         ford      test        212           1.28      9.0        4.9
456     new         bmw       awesome                   3.33      3.33
789     new         bmw       cool        123           2.23      1.99       9.89
987     new         bmw       cool        123           2.23      1.99       9.89
...            ...              ...           ...           ...         ...         ...
```

As you can see from the above, the SKU field is unique, but all the other data has populated based on other rows. The conditions are based on Condition, Make, Model, Derivative but these may change in the future. The column names also change regulary so it needs to be dynamic without the need of modifying the query to add the new columns.

If there are rows with the same Condition, Make, Model, Derivative but different height, length or depth then it should keep that value.

Sorry if I haven't explained in depth enough.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Suggestion that I can't test right now:  `GROUP BY condition, make, model, derivative`, and use `GROUP_CONCAT(height) as height, GROUP_CONCAT(length) as length, ...` - GROUP_CONCAT has a couple arguments, so fiddling with those might get you what you need.  However, this would only work if you can _guarantee_ those fields are filled in only once for each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sku, condition, make, model, derivative,
       IFNULL(t1.height, t2.height) height, 
       IFNULL(t1.length, t2.length) length,
       IFNULL(t1.depth, t2.depth) depth
FROM mytable t1
JOIN (SELECT condition, make, model, derivative,
             MAX(height) height, MAX(length) length, MAX(depth) depth
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY condition, make, model, derivative) t2
USING (condition, make, model, derivative)
```

This won't update automatically when you add new columns. To do that, you'll have to write dynamic SQL using the `information_schema` table to get all the column names. Now that you see the general structure of the query, I hope you can figure that part out on your own.

Comment: I don't think he's asking for MAX, he has also said he needs other values of height if it is available

Comment: The `IFNULL` check makes it only replace the empty values.

Comment: If there are multiple heights, I have to pick one to substitute -- I use the max.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it needs to be a select query, no updates can take place. (Sorry I didn't add that).

Answer (score 0):

You need different combination of Height, depth, Length for Group by columns, rt?

So, what if there are two distinct values of available to Length, but only on value available for Height and depth. How you are going to deal with that. The below query will produce two results in that case

```
    SELECT M.SKU, M.Condition, M.Make, M.Model, M.Derivative, HGHT.HEIGHT, HGHT.LENGTH, HGHT.DEPTH
FROM
MY_TBL AS M 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Condition, Make, Model, Derivative , MAX(height) AS HEIGHT, MAX(LENGTH) AS LENGTH, MAX(DEPTH) AS DEPTH
    FROM MY_TBL
    GROUP BY Condition, Make, Model, Derivative 
) AS HGHT
ON M.CONDITION = HGHT.CONDITION
AND M.MAKE = HGHT.MAKE
AND M.MODEL = HGHT.MODEL
AND M.DERIVATIVE = HGHT.DERIVATIVE
```

Comment: It would select the highest value of the said column. There always needs to be the same amount of rows as before, but the data within each column needs to be populated with the best possible available data based on the Condition, Make, Model, Derivative columns. If there is duplicate data such as two rows which are the same Condition, Make, Model, Deriviatve, then it should get the highest value of the said column (i.e. highest hight or length etc).

Comment: @verheesj Your question says that if it already has a value, it should keep that value. Now you say it should get the highest?

Comment: It should only get the highest value if the said column is empty. If it already contains a value, then it shouldn't change the value. If the column happens to be empty, then it should get the highest value of another row based on the Make, Model, Derivative etc.

Comment: I think we are totally confused. You need to say us what exactly you need and provide us with results you expect which includes all scenarios that you expect to deal